# Count checked checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to count and calculate selected checkboxes. They are by default checked. I have 6 checkboxes and need to display in other field. Basically, when they are all checked in a field I need to show 100% and if I uncheck one box the show 83.4% etc.

I found some jQuery script on this forum but they all user `class` as a reference point to jQuery script. The problem is that I have same `class="flat"` in other fields.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="item form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="Uvod" value="1" class="flat" checked /> Uvod
  <br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="Ponuda/Prodajni_Pristup" value="1" class="flat" checked /> Ponuda/Prodajni Pristup
  <br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="Alternaticna_ponuda" value="1" class="flat" checked /> Alternaticna ponuda
  <br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="Profesionalizam" value="1" class="flat" checked /> Profesionalizam
  <br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="Motivacija" value="1" class="flat" checked /> Motivacija
  <br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="Dodatan_kriterij" value="1" class="flat" /> <b>Dodatan kriterij</b>
  <br />            

  <select class="flat" name="Dodatni_kriterij_odabir" value="<?php echo $values['Dodatni_kriterij_odabir']?>">
    <option disabled selected hidden=></option>
    <option>MBB</option>
    <option>Cross-sell</option>
    <option>#N/A</option>
  </select> Dodatni kriterij odabir
  <br />              
</div>
```

This is the field i would like to show result of % checked boxes:

```
<div class="item form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Score">Score <span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" id="Edit_Score" name="Score" value="0" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any other way to count checkboxes but not using `class` (maybe input id?)

Comment: just use a different class name

Comment: You can have more than one class in the `class` field: e.g. `class="flat countedcheckbox"`

Comment: Or add a second class, you can have multiple classes. Additionally your `select` shouldn't have a `value` the `option`s should have values.

Comment: what does this have to do with mysql? and php also; there's no code for those tags.

Comment: voted as unclear

Answer (score 2):

You can select all checkboxes with`$('[type=checkbox]')` or with `$(':checkbox')`. You can then look at `.attr('checked')`. If you want all of the inputs that are for that specific input value, you can use `$("input[name='hobbies[]']")`.

```
var total = $("input[name='hobbies[]']").length;
var checked = $("input[name='hobbies[]']:checked").length;

var percentage = Math.floor((checked / total) * 100);
```

Comment: i manage to write whole script:
`var hobbies = document.getElementsByName('hobbies[]');
var total = $("input[name='hobbies[]']").length;
var checked = $("input[name='hobbies[]']:checked").length;
var percentage = Math.floor((checked / total) * 100);
$("#Score").val(percentage);`

how can i run that code every time i click on any checkbox to update `#Score` field?

Comment: You'll need to watch for a .change event.

Comment: thank you, I manage to solve this. but find out that script won't work when I apply `class` to checkbox input field.

Answer (score 0):

An element can have more classes. Use `class="flat"` for your styling and add another for your `jQuery`

`class="flat"` can become `class="flat counter"` and change your `jQuery` to count the elements with the `counter` class.